# Ruby Time comparison mayhem and chaos. An unsolvable mystery

Tags: ruby

Look, here's the thing... There is absolutely no reason why this is not working. However, I've decided to publicly come here and express my discontent and frustration towards this piece of code. For as much as I love Ruby I believe there are things coming past me unseen. Please, take a look at it.

```
def pull(start_time=10.minutes.ago.utc, end_time=Time.now.utc)
  count = 0
  binding.pry
  while start_time.utc <= end_time.utc do
    count =+ 1
    start_time = (start_time + 1.minute).utc
  end
  p "Count is at #{count}, and start_time is at #{start_time}"
end
```

I've tried to compare Time objects multiple times and in many different ways but I could never make an incremental loop using this comparison. I've been inside the loop and appended the `binding.pry` to inspect the values of `start_time`. It's properly being incremented. But the loop is failing to be making any logical sense.

To experiment, I have also printed a message at the end to check the values of the counter `count` to see how many times the loop is going through. It stops after the first round. Immediately after `start_time` gets assigned a new value inside the loop. This is the only message I have from calling this method.

```
"Count is at 1, and start_time is at 2020-01-26 17:49:37 UTC"
```

I look forward to hearing suggestions about something unseen and escaping me. Because I came from Rails I admit I'm not entirely sure about all Ruby's default libraries and how to use them.

By the way, to run this code you will have to require these:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric'
require 'pry'
```

Comment: I understand your frustration. The thing is, there's *always* a reason when some code doesn't work as expected. It might be very complex or surprising, it doesn't mean there's no reason, though. Keep on looking!

Comment: BTW, what do you want to calculate, exactly? What's your goal?

Comment: Thanks, Eric. This is a pull method in a sophisticated script to fetch roughly 500K records daily. I am not a developer and I had to code this all by myself because this applies to Trading and Finance. All of these records are used to create signals and eventually open trading positions. The reason for the while loop is that requests are limited to 1K records at a time.

Comment: I don't think you should reinvent the wheel and write your own scheduler, then. https://github.com/javan/whenever, https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job or https://itnext.io/sidekiq-overview-and-how-to-deploy-it-to-heroku-b8811fea9347 might be able to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing `count =+ 1`, not `count += 1` like you intended.

Here's the corrected version:

```
def pull(start_time=10.minutes.ago.utc, end_time=Time.now.utc)
  count = 0
  while start_time.utc <= end_time.utc do
    count += 1
    start_time = (start_time + 1.minute).utc
  end
  p "Count is at #{count}, and start_time is at #{start_time}"
end
```

Output with corrected version:

```
=> "Count is at 11, and start_time is at 2020-01-26 18:41:22 UTC"
```

Comment: Correct. `count =+ 1` means `count = +1` to Ruby. Mistyping the `+=` shorthand strikes once again.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be a full answer but I think it could prevent you from having yet another headache:

```
def pull(start_time=10.minutes.ago, end_time=Time.now)
```

This line looks simple enough but there's a problem lurking: When no argument is sent, `start_time` will be initialized to `10.minutes.ago` and `end_time` will be initialized to `Time.now`.

The problem is that `end_time` will be initialized a few microseconds after `start_time`, so the difference between both will be 10 minutes + a few microseconds, which is strictly longer than 10 minutes:

```
 10.minutes.ago - Time.now
 => -600.000279946
```

In the other direction, it would be a bit shorter than 10 minutes:

```
Time.now - 10.minutes.ago
# => 599.999981608
```

You might want to divide by 60 and round to avoid this problem:

```
(Time.now - 10.minutes.ago) / 60
#=> 9.99999967125
((Time.now - 10.minutes.ago) / 60).round
#=> 10
```

Comment: Eh. What's a few spare microseconds here or there? :-)

Comment: Instead of rounding, you could set the default argument values to `nil` and conditionally assign the correct values within the method.

Comment: @Stefan: I'm not sure I understand your point. What are the correct values? Do you mean you want to define `now` first and then define `start_time` as `now - 600`?

Comment: @EricDuminil something like that, yes. "Correct" is having both values exactly 10 minutes apart.

Comment: Or maybe `def pull(start_time=nil, end_time=Time.now)` and then `start_time ||= 10.minutes.before(end_time)`.

Comment: @Stefan: It could work. What OP really needs is some kind of background processing, e.g. with ActiveJob & Sidekiq